# how can i add a timer on my game which is not reseting when my character dies

Tags: timer, reset, scene

for reseting my scene i use in my game manager

```
void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
```

and for my timer i use

```
void Update()
    {
        float t = Time.time - startTime;

        string milis = ((t-(int)t) * 1000).ToString("f0");
        string minuttes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
        string secomds = (t % 60).ToString("f0");

        timerText.text = minuttes + ":" + secomds + ":" + milis;

    }
```

But every time my scene restarts the timer resets 
is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

after 1 week i finally managed to fix it i just deleted the -startTime